# Constructing a Borel set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have to make a Borel set $E \subset R $ such that $ 0 < m(E \cap I) < m(E)$, for all real segment $I$, where $ m $ is the Lebesgue measure.
I also have to say if it is possible for E to have $m(E)< \infty$

I know that I have to take a dense sequence $(r_j)$, such as $Q$, $a_j > 0$ such that $a_k > \sum_{j=k+1} ^{\infty} {a_j}$ , such as $ a_j = 1/3^j$, and then define $I_j = (r_j-a_j,r_j+a_j)$ , $E_k= I_k \setminus \bigcup _{j=k+1}^{\infty} {I_j} $, and finaly $E = \bigcup E_k$.

I just don't know how to calculate its measure, nor how to prove that $m(E)$ can or can't be finite.

Comment: $mE \le \sum_k mI_k \le 2 \sum_k {1 \over 3^k} < \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $J_n$ be an enumeration of all intervals with rational endpoints.

We construct two disjoint Cantor like sets(or ''fat'' Cantor sets) $A_1,B_1 \subseteq J_1$ and $0<m(A_1),m(B_1)<\frac{1}{2}$

Inductively we choose disjoint Cantor like sets $A_n,B_n \subseteq J_n\setminus \bigcup_{m<n}(A_m \cup B_m)$ and $0<m(A_n),m(B_n)<\frac{1}{2^n}$

The desired set is $C:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$

Note that $C$ is Borel as a  countable union of Borel sets.

Comment: What happens in the end with $B_n$? You have not used it for constructing C, I don't understand its role in the proof

Comment: @AdolfoGarcia...   You consntruct two disjoint Cantor sets in every interval and take  in the the union only  one of those in each interval to have the inequality $m(I \cap A)<m(I)$,..in general you do this proceedure to avoid $m(A \cap I)=m(I)$ for the Borel set $A$ you constructed.

Comment: So it is safer not to take both Cantor  sets in the countable union.